# Can output from c command system() go into a file instead of displaying on the console?

Tags: c, linux

Can output from c command system() go into a file instead of displaying on the console?

Output of the

```
  system ("echo 123")
```

command that I use in c and then run it on Linux. It prints

```
123
```

on the screen. But if I write:

```
  system ("echo 123 >null")
```

it says cannot create file null. Can somebody please tell me how I can call this

```
system("echo 123")
```

without it displaying anything on the terminal. Any help is greatly appreciated.

The error message I recieve when I write

```
system("echo 123 > null")
```

Output

```
null: cannot create
```

I am sorry this post is growing longer. OK! The problem is I have my own application that I am calling using System command. This application is in myapp/bin, the code that I am running is in another Folder c_prog/mycode.x .

Now I have full rights in myapp/bin and also in c_prog/mycode.x but I am getting the same problem

Comment: Surely you should be redirecting to `/dev/null` in your system call? Or even better `system ("echo 123 > /dev/null 2>&1");` handling both `stdout` and `stderr`. If you actually want it to go to the file "null" you probably have permissions problems instead. Is your question to hide output from the terminal or put output into a file?

Comment: The redirection *should* work, as [`system`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/system.3.html) actually calls a shell which means everything that works in a shell should work in the `system` function call. The problem here is more likely that you don't have write-access to the working directory. Please edit your question to include the *actual* error message.

Comment: Which is the current directory when you run the program?  Is it your directory?  Or is it a system directory such as `/` — the root directory?  You shouldn't be able to create files in `/` or many other directories (`/usr`, `/bin`, `/lib`, `/home`, …); you should be able to create them in your own directories (`/home/you`, `/home/you/src`, …).

Comment: Perhaps change `system("echo 123")` to `/* system("echo 123") */`

Comment: @EdHeal is this a joke mate?

Comment: @ITguy: Yes, it is a joke — unless you intended to write to `/dev/null`, in which case it is a major performance optimization.

Comment: It fulfills your requirements. Not very clear what you are trying to achieve from the question

Comment: @EdHeal Ok now I understand why this would bother you. This echo 123 examply was just to explain my question. This is not what I was trying to do. I have edited the question now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your rights on the working directory.
If you don't have write-access surely you cannot create the file in the working directory in which case a `sudo chmod 755 your_directory` will help to give read and write rights.

Words of cautions. You might to check why you cannot write in the directory. There may be a very good reason for that. If the directory is not yours you may want to be careful before messing with it. One suggestion would also be then to change your working directory to a directory you created yourself.

Comment: Your diagnosis is correct; I don't think the prescription is necessarily correct.  If you can't write in the directory, there's probably a good reason (it isn't yours to write it).  Also, `666` permissions on a directory are useless; you can find out what files are in it, and you might be able to delete them, but you can't access them.  755 permission is a more plausible choice (777 is a bad choice).

Answer (score 0):

I figured the problem out... and yeah I was making a silly mistake. In the folder I was trying to create this null file I already had a null named Folder.

Silly me! That is why it was not creating a file of that same name... however Linux could have given me a more appropriate warning.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible as well easy. Just use the pipe operator to redirect one command's output to input of second command(you want 'cat'). Like following

```
system("echo 'Hello World' | cat ./file.txt");
```

Here command echo give output "Hello World", which is redirected using |(pipe) operator and then this be the input of cat command, which writes it to file ./file.txt. See cat command before use.

Comment: No needs for `cat`or piping here `system("echo 'Hello World' > file.txt");`
Or with pure php `file_put_contents("file.txt",""Hello world);`